# Find number of close stores, using a matrix of distances

Tags: r, dplyr, r-sf

I have a matrix of stores and their relative distance to each other similar to this table with 3000 rows and 3000 columns. I want to create a new table that shows the number of stores that are 5km or closer to each store.

|  | store 1 |
| --- | --- |
| store 1 | NA |
| store 2 | 200 (M) |

I have created this distance matrix using a data frame, which has the x coordinates and y coordinates of each store.

```
dist_matrix <- st_distance(df)
diag(dist_matrix) <- NA
```

This gives me a matrix containing store distance to the next one in meters.

I want to find the number of stores that are located in a 5km radius to each store. I have tried to do this:
`

```
#making the matrix into a data frame
dist_matrix <- data.frame(dist_matrix)
names(dist_matrix) <- df$store_id
rownames(dist_matrix) <- df$store_id

close <- dist_matrix %>%
mutate(ID=rownames(.)) %>%
gather('closest','dist',-ID) %>%
filter(!is.na(dist)) %>%
arrange(dist)
```

But it does not seem to work. Does anyone have input on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you could find useful to use the base function `colSums()`, paired with a logical matrix of distances less than whatever threshold you need.

As I don't have access to your data I will use distance matrix of my three favorite North Carolina towns (because of the `nc.shp` that lives in {sf}).

What this example does is:

- it calculates a distance matrix of the three cities, dropping units dimension to ease calculation (no need to remember that we are talking meters)
- gives the distance matrix names to make it easier to work with
- creates a logical matrix `logi` of distances less than 150000 meters
- calculates column sums over the matrix of distances less than 150000 meters.

Note that each city is automatically included (having zero distance - it is on diagonal of the original matrix). So you will need to subtract one. Or, as you you did in your original code, set diagonal to NA and do the `colSums()` with `na.rm = TRUE` / it should not matter which one you do, as long as you do one of the two.

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

cities <- data.frame(name = c("Raleigh", "Greensboro", "Wilmington"),
                     x = c(-78.633333, -79.819444, -77.912222),
                     y = c(35.766667, 36.08, 34.223333)) %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 4326)


result <- cities %>% 
  st_distance() %>% 
  units::drop_units()

colnames(result) <- cities$name

logi <- result < 150000 # here will be your 500 meters

colSums(logi)
# Raleigh Greensboro Wilmington 
#       2          2          1
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I think this worked! But I just wondered if this is including its own location as a close store? I think it does.

Comment: yup, that is why I wrote the note in my answer :) Either subtract one, or set the diagonal to NA (= not zero!) and do the colSums with na.rm = T argument

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
dist_matrix |>
  filter_all(all_vars(.<=5000)) #assuming 5000m
```

Comment: This did not work for me, but thank you for the answer!